# how to safely remove usb storage?

Tags: usb-host-mode

My android 2.3 tablet supports usb. It mounts all usb drives. However there is no mechanism for unmounting in the settings menu.

On direct unplugging usb devices, i get notification " usb mass storage device removed unexpectedly

Is there is an app for unmounting usb storage devices?

Comment: Can you pull down the notification bar and dismount from there?

Answer (score 6):

It should normally be located within settings>storage>unmount USB storage. Otherwise look within whatever file explorer you are using on the tablet for USB storage, this should indicate that a usb stick etc is using the drive, and hence give you the option to remove/unmount.

There are apps available but these require root access to my knowledge.

Comment: In my unrooted stock Moto G running 4.3, I can access my USB pen drive by using an USB OTG cable. I use ES File explorer. I do not find any options to safely eject/remove the drive neither in ES File explorer app nor in settings->storage. Without safely ejecting, the drive is not detected again unless I restart my phone. Any ideas?

Comment: What about Android 5.0.2 ? I can't find any option to unmount USB Storage !

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an unmount option too, on Android 4.4.2. The answer was given in the comment from Matthew Read: pull down the notication bar (swipe from the top). Then you should see a button to unmount USB devices. At least it works like that on my LG G2.

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer. Many ways to get here. Drag the windows out from the left in Es file explorer. You should see Favorite, Local, Library, Network and Tools in a colume. Tap on Local and you should see the usbdisk with an arrow beside it. Tap the arrow and you are taken to Storage Settings. Scroll to the bottom and tap on Unmount USB Storage. I'm using a S4 running CM12.

Answer (score 1):

In kitkat 4.4.2 there is a way to safely remove usb otg device.

Settings>storage>usb>unmount

In storage menu, it shows internal storage,sd card and usb. You have to select the usb storage and inside, you will find an option to unmount.

Answer (score -1):

You upgrade your moto g to Android 4.4 kit Kat. After that u don't want to restart your phone on ejection of USB drive. But still there is no safe ejection method as this specification (OTG) is not specified by manufacturer.  The advantage is that you don't need to restart your android device.

Comment: Where does the OP say anything about the Moto G?